# Dirac delta convolution

Tags: dirac-delta

How can this identity convolution be shown?

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}  f(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau=f(t)$$

I keep getting stuck in traps when trying to show this and need a bit of assistance

Comment: What is your definition of $\delta$ distribution? (So, what do you mean with your Left Hand Side?)

Comment: Also, what kind of thing is $f$? Is it a continuous function, a distribution, an $L^p$ function, ...?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *proof* of the formula you're asking, this is a definition. However, here is the way why the expression is used in so many contexts.

Consider a sequence of function
$$
\delta_\epsilon(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\epsilon},&-\epsilon<x<\epsilon,\\
0,&\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

It is reasonable to expect that
$$
\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\delta_\epsilon(x).
$$

Now consider the integral and assume that we are free to change the order of operations:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(x)f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R}\delta_{\epsilon}(x)f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{2\epsilon} f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}2\epsilon\cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon} f(\xi),
$$
where due to the mean value theorem $\xi\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Hence we can conclude that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(\xi)=f(0),
$$
which gives you a "*proof*" of the original formula.

Now just repeat the same for $\delta (x-a)$, or $\delta(t-\tau)$ if you prefer.

Comment: Its maybe two definitions, if one adopts $\langle \delta(t-\tau) , f(t) \rangle := \langle \delta(t) , f(t+\tau) \rangle $ (which can of course be defined for other distributions too)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one needs to understand that the Dirac delta is *not* a function, but a distribution, ie an element of the dual space of some space of test functions. Thus, one *defines* the Dirac delta by its action on smooth, compactly supported function
$$\delta(f):=f(0)\ ,$$
and one writes (this is just notation!)
$$\delta(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta(t)f(t)dt\ .$$
One then *defines* $\delta(t-\tau)$ by a formal change of variable $u = t-\tau$:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta(t-\tau)f(t)dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta(u)f(u+\tau)dt = f(\tau)\ .$$

*Note:* Sorry, I switched $t$ and $\tau$ with respect to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not provide the proof but aims to provide signal-theoretic insight.

I am myself figuring this, and the answer, I believe lies in distribution theory; for dirac delta has been defined so, for its purported usage in signal theory as singularity "signal".
$$\int \delta(t) dt = 1 $$

All the answers above are justified and would satisfy any undergrad, such as me. To add one more observation.
$$(f* \delta) (t) = \int f(\tau)\delta (t - \tau) d \tau \implies f(t)$$

Wouldn't that make $\delta(t)$ a "convolution kernel" for any function (signal).

If so, in a system (a transformation $f : x \to y$ ) having an impulse response $h(t) = f(\delta(t))$, it would be immensely helpful to realise that the output... $$ y(t) = x(t)*h(t) $$ how? with a criminal lack of mathematical insight, I believe, ($\delta(t)$ being the kernel) h(t) upon convoluting, purely (zero state?) communicates just specification of the system.

Answer (score -2):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(\tau) \, \delta(t-\tau) \, d\tau
= \{ \tau = t-\sigma \}
= \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(t-\sigma) \, \delta(\sigma) \, (-d\sigma) \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t-\sigma) \, \delta(\sigma) \, d\sigma
= f(t-0)
= f(t).
$$

Comment: This does not actually provide a proof. You just changed the arguments, but still the proof of why the very last identity "works" is missing.

Comment: Why the very last identity, $f(t-0) = f(t),$ works? Isn't that obvious?